# Generate text from bash script with literal double quotes

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to automate string replace thing for my project ...
I need output like this in file

```
insert into libraries values("Schema_name",  "table_name",  "table_name",   "/data/Projects/Ope/ACT/Domain/Code/Files");
```

and what I am getting in the file is

```
`insert into libraries values(Schema_name,  table_name,  table_name,   /data/Projects/Ope/ACT/Domain/Code/Files)`;
```

### replace_script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  param1=`echo $line | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'`
  param2=`echo $line | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'`
  echo "insert into libraries values(\"$param1\",\"$param2\",\"$param2\",\"/data/Projects/Ope/ACT/Domain/Code/Files\");" >> input_queries.hql
done <<EOF
schema_name table_name
schema_name table_name
EOF
```

Comment: This is, to be clear, a Very Bad Idea. Use a scripting language that has bind variable support to properly pass your SQL values out-of-band from query text -- anything else means you're vulnerable to injection attacks.

Comment: BTW, `while read -r param1 param2` would be **way** more efficient than `while read line`, and then splitting the line.

Comment: any idea why this is not printing double quote?

Comment: It *is* printing double quotes. Absolutely does. Your claim that it isn't is simply false.

Comment: See http://ideone.com/5N7NkQ, showing your script running with its output  -- having literal double quotes in same.

Comment: Now, that said, SQL doesn't use double quotes for values; it uses *single* quotes for that.

Comment: I am running the same script but its not printing double quote for me.

Comment: If you can't generate a reproducer someone else can use to see the same problem, how do you expect anyone to help you? Please try to generate an ideone link that shows your bug.

Comment: BTW, it's more efficient to put `>> input_queries.hql` on the `done` line for your loop, not on the individual `echo`. When you put it on the `echo`, the shell opens the file before each `echo` and closes it again after; when you put it after the `done`, then the shell leaves the file open for the whole loop.

Comment: As another aside -- `echo $line | ...` has a number of bugs in its own right (it expands globs, splits on any characters in IFS, has [undefined behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/echo.html) in the event that data contains literal backslashes, etc). `echo "$line"` is safer, and `printf '%s\n' "$line"` even better than that -- though you'd be better off just `read`ing directly into multiple variables in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

The exact code given in your question emits as output:

```
insert into libraries values("schema_name","table_name","table_name","/data/Projects/Ope/ACT/Domain/Code/Files");
insert into libraries values("schema_name","table_name","table_name","/data/Projects/Ope/ACT/Domain/Code/Files");
```

This is, as I understand it, exactly what you claim to want.

---

However, SQL doesn't use double quotes for data -- it uses *single* quotes for that.

```
escape_sql() {
  local val
  val=${1//\\/\\\\}
  val=${val//\'/\\\'}
  val=${val//\"/\\\"}
  printf '%s' "$val"
}

while read -r param1 param2; do
  printf $'insert into libraries values(\'%s\', \'%s\', \'%s\', \'/data/Projects/Ope/ACT/Domain/Code/Files\');\\n' \
    "$(escape_sql "$param1")" \
    "$(escape_sql "$param2")" \
    "$(escape_sql "$param2")"
done <<EOF
schema_name table_name
schema_name table_name
EOF
```

The above makes a rudimentary attempt to prevent malicious values from escaping their quotes -- though you should really use a language with native SQL bindings for your database for the purpose!

---

That said -- this is *not* safe escaping against malicious data (for instance, data containing literal quotes). For that, use a language built-to-purpose.

Comment: I am running the same script but its not printing double quote for me.

Comment: @aashish, see the ideone link I posted, showing double quotes being printed. Since that's a 3rd-party tool, and it shows the quotes, anyone else is going to have that same behavior. Can you generate an example on ideone, or somewhere else people can see it with the output, that shows your quotes not being shown?

Comment: Can space be a issue? if space length is different between schema_name and table_name in  multiple lines

Comment: Again -- if you can generate a reproducer someone else can use to see the same problem, then we'll know what the issue is. If I can't see the problem myself, then all I can do is guess.

Comment: I am so sorry guys, I is working but somehow output file was not getting updating. Its working fine now

Comment: Thanks for the help mate

Comment: Glad to help. (Maybe the working directory when this was being run was different than you expected, so the updated output file is in a different place than the copy you were looking at?) -- BTW, if you can't edit the question into a place where it's helpful to other people, you might consider deleting it.